# I need your help. About the statsmodel.api & statsmodel.formula.api , Dll load failed : dll load failed the specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, importerror, statsmodels

The code I'm trying to execute is this.

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as statm
import statsmodels.formula.api as statfa
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
...
...
```

Excuting ...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/aboi/PycharmProjects/deeplearning/deep_class/05_3D_Graph.py", line 2, in <module>
    import statsmodels.api as statm
  File "C:\Users\aboi\.conda\envs\hw\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\api.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import regression
  File "C:\Users\aboi\.conda\envs\hw\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .linear_model import yule_walker
  File "C:\Users\aboi\.conda\envs\hw\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py", line 40, in <module>
    from scipy import stats
  File "C:\Users\aboi\.conda\envs\hw\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 379, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "C:\Users\aboi\.conda\envs\hw\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 182, in <module>
    from . import distributions
  File "C:\Users\aboi\.conda\envs\hw\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\distributions.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ._distn_infrastructure import (entropy, rv_discrete, rv_continuous,
  File "C:\Users\aboi\.conda\envs\hw\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py", line 24, in <module>
    from scipy import optimize
  File "C:\Users\aboi\.conda\envs\hw\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\__init__.py", line 391, in <module>
    from ._minimize import *
  File "C:\Users\aboi\.conda\envs\hw\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 30, in <module>
    from ._trustregion_constr import _minimize_trustregion_constr
  File "C:\Users\aboi\.conda\envs\hw\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_trustregion_constr\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .minimize_trustregion_constr import _minimize_trustregion_constr
  File "C:\Users\aboi\.conda\envs\hw\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_trustregion_constr\minimize_trustregion_constr.py", line 4, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator
  File "C:\Users\aboi\.conda\envs\hw\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py", line 116, in <module>
    from .eigen import *
  File "C:\Users\aboi\.conda\envs\hw\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .arpack import *
  File "C:\Users\aboi\.conda\envs\hw\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .arpack import *
  File "C:\Users\aboi\.conda\envs\hw\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\arpack.py", line 45, in <module>
    from . import _arpack
ImportError: DLL load failed: dll load failed the specified procedure could not be found.
```

in conda env...
install finish (numpy, statsmodels, pandas, matplotlib)
but
conda install statsmodels.api

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - statsmodels.api

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

and conda install statsmodels.formula.api... too!

1. Why not? import statsmodels.api, import statsmodels.formula.api
2. why not? conda install statsmodels.api, import statsmodels.formula.api

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

It was really a simple question.

1. conda remove statsmodels
2. pip install statsmodels

I suffered from this problem for three days.